# i run this code but showing router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn) this error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```js
//jshint esversion:6
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();
    app.use("view-engine", "ejs");
    app.get("/", function(req, res){
var today = new Date();
var currentDay = today.getDay();
var day = "";
if (currentDay === 6 || currentDay === 0) {
  day = "Weekend";
}else {
  day = "weekday";
}
res.render("list" , {kindofDay:  day});
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

i can't see where i have gone wrong. Can anybody see? whenever i run this app.js showing that router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn) this error.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>To Do List</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>It's a <%= kindofDay %></h1>
  </body>
  </html>
```

This is my list.ejs file..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! `app.use("view-engine", "ejs");` should read `app.set("view-engine", "ejs");`

Answer (score 0):

`app.use([path,] callback [, callback...])` -> This code is what you use when you want a specific callback function to run at a specific path. This is called a [middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use).

`app.set(name, value)` -> This code is what you use when you want assign a value to some variable. You can uyse any name, but certain names can be used to configure the behavior of the server.
One of these `name`s is `view engine` (notice there is no hyphen). It will set the [template engine](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html) to use.

If your aim is to set `ejs` as your template engine, just do `app.set("view engine", "ejs");`